# How can I create a dictionary from a list of string?

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

So, I have this, for example:

```
['Apple', 'Red', 'Banana', 'Yellow']
```

and I need to return

```
 {'Apple': 'Red', 'Banana': 'Yellow'}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to turn a list of strings into a dictionary with the odd-indexed strings as keys and even-indexed ones as values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303213/pythonic-way-to-turn-a-list-of-strings-into-a-dictionary-with-the-odd-indexed-st)

Answer (score 1):

Just slice the list and use `dict` :

```
>>> li=['Apple', 'Red', 'Banana', 'Yellow']
>>> dict((li[:2],li[2:]))
{'Apple': 'Red', 'Banana': 'Yellow'}
```

Comment: The only issue is that the list is an user input and I won't know how long the list would be

Answer (score 1):

If it's a list like `[k1, v1, k2, v2, ...]` just use slicing and `zip`:

```
>>> l = ['Apple', 'Red', 'Banana', 'Yellow']
>>> dict(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))
{'Banana': 'Yellow', 'Apple': 'Red'}
```

---

Like this you first create two list, one containing the keys, the other containing the values:

```
>>> k, v = l[::2], l[1::2]
>>> k
['Apple', 'Banana']
>>> v
['Red', 'Yellow']
```

Then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) creates an iterator of tuples (pairs of key and value in this case):

```
>>> list(zip(k, v))
[('Apple', 'Red'), ('Banana', 'Yellow')]
```

This iterator then can be used to create the dictionary.

Comment: Yes! I just saw that in another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303213/pythonic-way-to-turn-a-list-of-strings-into-a-dictionary-with-the-odd-indexed-st) my fault for not looking hard enough... :( but I don't understand how it works; can you explain please?

Comment: @newbie94 hope this helps

Comment: Is there a way I can write that another way? I need to use it in a function and that is what I need to return. When I write return dict(zip(o[::2], o[1::2])) it says return out of function.

Comment: @newbie94 like it says, you put this statement outsite of a function. Maybe an indention problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x you can just use the [dict comprehension syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
d = {key: value for (key, value) in item}
```

you can use the item in any way you want.